# How to dropdown custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

To make a dropdown list from categories I can use **wp_dropdown_categories** function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

But how can I do the same thing but for my custom taxnomy called e.g. post_city ?

So, far I tried:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => array(
           'post_city',
         ) 
    );
    ?>
<?php wp_dropdown_categories($args); ?>
```

but only the first tag is shown in the dropdown ;(

Comment: You can't answer your question within. Please separate the solution from the question and post it as an answer.

Comment: ok,now it's fixed ;).

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!! ;D

I need to use `'hide_empty' => 0` instead of `'hide_empty' => 1` in the arguments array like:

```
<?php 
        $args = array(
            'taxonomy' => array(
               'post_city',
             ),
            'hide_empty' => 0
        );
    ?>
```